# How can I build docker with .pyc (pycache) files of my project

Tags: python, docker

I had run this:

```
docker build -t image_name .
```

and docker built successfully
but when I run it I get this error:

```
bad magic number
```

there is not a way to make docker with pycache files?

Comment: What does the error says?

Comment: What do you want to do; do you want to convert the py files in the docker when you docker build and only ship your image with .pyc or do you only have precompiled files?

Comment: Could you include the `Dockerfile`? Might make it easier to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @filt bad magic number in .pyc

Comment: @ersteller I want to build docker with .pyc files not .py files

Comment: as far as my understanding `bad magic number` error is caused by the change in the `.py` files are not reflected by the `.pyc` files this can be resolved by removing all the `.pyc` files and compile again.

Comment: I run these .pyc files without docker and I don't get any error. just by running with docker I get this **bad magic number** @google

Comment: copy .py files into your image build context and then create your .pyc in the dockerfile "RUN python -m compileall ."

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your .py files to .pyc like so:

```
python -m compileall .
```

you should compile with the same version of python that you run in your docker container

By the error, I assume you use different versions for both tasks.

Comment: my python versions are the same, but I get this error.  is another important  except python versions?

Comment: Which Operating system do you use? Do you build your python files on the host system and copy them to the image or do you are you compiling it in the Dockerfile that you use for running and delete the .py files? Do you run on a raspberry pi maybe?

Comment: I did `python -m compileall .` and built docker on created .pyc files. @ersteller